# OpenStack with Docker fails to spawn instances

Tags: docker, openstack, openstack-nova

I am trying to integrate Docker into OpenStack (Icehouse 2014.1.3) but OpenStack fails to start the instances.

On compute node, in /var/log/nova/compute.log:

```
2014-12-02 08:34:23.167 22606 ERROR nova.compute.manager [req-ce2cd284-0ab7-48a8-ba17-d18ecb59e0a4 2f33bf612258455b86d28f0841d9b9fb 1bfa9d3fcdc8464ba3bca4f636813ea6] [instance: 67c886e1-71f7-4d94-a099-b4d485a12125] Instance failed to spawn
2014-12-02 08:34:23.167 22606 TRACE nova.compute.manager [instance: 67c886e1-71f7-4d94-a099-b4d485a12125] Traceback (most recent call last):
2014-12-02 08:34:23.167 22606 TRACE nova.compute.manager [instance: 67c886e1-71f7-4d94-a099-b4d485a12125]   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 1737, in _spawn
2014-12-02 08:34:23.167 22606 TRACE nova.compute.manager [instance: 67c886e1-71f7-4d94-a099-b4d485a12125]     block_device_info)
2014-12-02 08:34:23.167 22606 TRACE nova.compute.manager [instance: 67c886e1-71f7-4d94-a099-b4d485a12125]   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/novadocker/virt/docker/driver.py", line 289, in spawn
2014-12-02 08:34:23.167 22606 TRACE nova.compute.manager [instance: 67c886e1-71f7-4d94-a099-b4d485a12125]     image = self._pull_missing_image(context, image_meta, instance)
2014-12-02 08:34:23.167 22606 TRACE nova.compute.manager [instance: 67c886e1-71f7-4d94-a099-b4d485a12125]   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/novadocker/virt/docker/driver.py", line 245, in _pull_missing_image
2014-12-02 08:34:23.167 22606 TRACE nova.compute.manager [instance: 67c886e1-71f7-4d94-a099-b4d485a12125]     fileutils.ensure_tree(snapshot_directory)
2014-12-02 08:34:23.167 22606 TRACE nova.compute.manager [instance: 67c886e1-71f7-4d94-a099-b4d485a12125]   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/nova/openstack/common/fileutils.py", line 37, in ensure_tree
2014-12-02 08:34:23.167 22606 TRACE nova.compute.manager [instance: 67c886e1-71f7-4d94-a099-b4d485a12125]     os.makedirs(path)
2014-12-02 08:34:23.167 22606 TRACE nova.compute.manager [instance: 67c886e1-71f7-4d94-a099-b4d485a12125]   File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/os.py", line 150, in makedirs
2014-12-02 08:34:23.167 22606 TRACE nova.compute.manager [instance: 67c886e1-71f7-4d94-a099-b4d485a12125]     makedirs(head, mode)
2014-12-02 08:34:23.167 22606 TRACE nova.compute.manager [instance: 67c886e1-71f7-4d94-a099-b4d485a12125]   File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
2014-12-02 08:34:23.167 22606 TRACE nova.compute.manager [instance: 67c886e1-71f7-4d94-a099-b4d485a12125]     mkdir(name, mode)
2014-12-02 08:34:23.167 22606 TRACE nova.compute.manager [instance: 67c886e1-71f7-4d94-a099-b4d485a12125] OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/instances'
2014-12-02 08:34:23.167 22606 TRACE nova.compute.manager [instance: 67c886e1-71f7-4d94-a099-b4d485a12125] 
2014-12-02 08:34:26.128 22606 ERROR nova.compute.manager [req-ce2cd284-0ab7-48a8-ba17-d18ecb59e0a4 2f33bf612258455b86d28f0841d9b9fb 1bfa9d3fcdc8464ba3bca4f636813ea6] [instance: 67c886e1-71f7-4d94-a099-b4d485a12125] Error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/instances'
2014-12-02 08:34:26.128 22606 TRACE nova.compute.manager [instance: 67c886e1-71f7-4d94-a099-b4d485a12125] Traceback (most recent call last):
2014-12-02 08:34:26.128 22606 TRACE nova.compute.manager [instance: 67c886e1-71f7-4d94-a099-b4d485a12125]   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 1328, in _build_instance
2014-12-02 08:34:26.128 22606 TRACE nova.compute.manager [instance: 67c886e1-71f7-4d94-a099-b4d485a12125]     set_access_ip=set_access_ip)
2014-12-02 08:34:26.128 22606 TRACE nova.compute.manager [instance: 67c886e1-71f7-4d94-a099-b4d485a12125]   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 393, in decorated_function
2014-12-02 08:34:26.128 22606 TRACE nova.compute.manager [instance: 67c886e1-71f7-4d94-a099-b4d485a12125]     return function(self, context, *args, **kwargs)
2014-12-02 08:34:26.128 22606 TRACE nova.compute.manager [instance: 67c886e1-71f7-4d94-a099-b4d485a12125]   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 1740, in _spawn
2014-12-02 08:34:26.128 22606 TRACE nova.compute.manager [instance: 67c886e1-71f7-4d94-a099-b4d485a12125]     LOG.exception(_('Instance failed to spawn'), instance=instance)
2014-12-02 08:34:26.128 22606 TRACE nova.compute.manager [instance: 67c886e1-71f7-4d94-a099-b4d485a12125]   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/nova/openstack/common/excutils.py", line 68, in __exit__
2014-12-02 08:34:26.128 22606 TRACE nova.compute.manager [instance: 67c886e1-71f7-4d94-a099-b4d485a12125]     six.reraise(self.type_, self.value, self.tb)
2014-12-02 08:34:26.128 22606 TRACE nova.compute.manager [instance: 67c886e1-71f7-4d94-a099-b4d485a12125]   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 1737, in _spawn
2014-12-02 08:34:26.128 22606 TRACE nova.compute.manager [instance: 67c886e1-71f7-4d94-a099-b4d485a12125]     block_device_info)
2014-12-02 08:34:26.128 22606 TRACE nova.compute.manager [instance: 67c886e1-71f7-4d94-a099-b4d485a12125]   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/novadocker/virt/docker/driver.py", line 289, in spawn
2014-12-02 08:34:26.128 22606 TRACE nova.compute.manager [instance: 67c886e1-71f7-4d94-a099-b4d485a12125]     image = self._pull_missing_image(context, image_meta, instance)
2014-12-02 08:34:26.128 22606 TRACE nova.compute.manager [instance: 67c886e1-71f7-4d94-a099-b4d485a12125]   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/novadocker/virt/docker/driver.py", line 245, in _pull_missing_image
2014-12-02 08:34:26.128 22606 TRACE nova.compute.manager [instance: 67c886e1-71f7-4d94-a099-b4d485a12125]     fileutils.ensure_tree(snapshot_directory)
2014-12-02 08:34:26.128 22606 TRACE nova.compute.manager [instance: 67c886e1-71f7-4d94-a099-b4d485a12125]   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/nova/openstack/common/fileutils.py", line 37, in ensure_tree
2014-12-02 08:34:26.128 22606 TRACE nova.compute.manager [instance: 67c886e1-71f7-4d94-a099-b4d485a12125]     os.makedirs(path)
2014-12-02 08:34:26.128 22606 TRACE nova.compute.manager [instance: 67c886e1-71f7-4d94-a099-b4d485a12125]   File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/os.py", line 150, in makedirs
2014-12-02 08:34:26.128 22606 TRACE nova.compute.manager [instance: 67c886e1-71f7-4d94-a099-b4d485a12125]     makedirs(head, mode)
2014-12-02 08:34:26.128 22606 TRACE nova.compute.manager [instance: 67c886e1-71f7-4d94-a099-b4d485a12125]   File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
2014-12-02 08:34:26.128 22606 TRACE nova.compute.manager [instance: 67c886e1-71f7-4d94-a099-b4d485a12125]     mkdir(name, mode)
2014-12-02 08:34:26.128 22606 TRACE nova.compute.manager [instance: 67c886e1-71f7-4d94-a099-b4d485a12125] OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/instances'
2014-12-02 08:34:26.128 22606 TRACE nova.compute.manager [instance: 67c886e1-71f7-4d94-a099-b4d485a12125]
```

Docker was installed following https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/Docker#Installing_Docker_for_OpenStack with a [modification](https://ask.openstack.org/en/question/49874/nova-docker-issue-import-error-no-module-named-i18n/)

```
git checkout -b pre-i18n 9045ca43b645e72751099491bf5f4f9e4bddbb91
```

Comment: Can you run a Docker from command line or through the REST API?

Comment: Thanks, I've figured what I did wrong (needed a docker image I wanted to start container from on a compute node, not on a node with Glance service)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I needed a docker image I wanted to start container from on a compute node, not on a node with Glance service.
Got everything to work now.